# Авторизация/регистрация в мобильном приложении для готового сайта

Tags: postgresql, ios, firebase, oauth, login

Есть рабочий сайт, сервер с пользовательскими данными, решили создать мобильное приложение, как лучше организовать авторизацию/регистрацию в ios приложении (вход только через почту+пароль): oauth, firebase или что-то еще более подходящее?

Просто firebase советуют делать, когда сервера нет, но тут все уже есть
И можно связать firebase с postgresql, конечно, но выглядит так, будто способ есть проще

Как лучше поступить?

Всем спасибо!